# Firefox covering up background image. In chrome everything looks fine

Tags: css, background

I have a class that creates a background image for a section of my project and everything looks fine in Chrome but in firefox there is no image. When I looked at firebug I notice that the background property of the class had `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` added to it. This is not in my css though. I do have other css classes with background images that are showing fine in firefox, only this one is not showing.

I tried tweaking things and searching for solutions but I'm drawing a blank. I have created a [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/GJordan/afzs48bx/) but the background displays fine there.

this is my class for the image:

```
.cover-wrapper-inner {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url($cover-image) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
```

Comment: I think you can check the line number, through which the style has been assigned. That might help you to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @IshanMadhusanka Thank you for the suggestion but I know where the style is and  `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`  is not in my code, Firefox is adding that. The code for that class is listed above.

Comment: Woke up this a.m. and problem seems to have resolved itself. I cleared cache a couple times last night but maybe it just lingered. Who knows...